# How do I construct a blaze rod harvester?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a blaze mob spawner in the Nether, now I'd like to build an automatic blaze rod harvester around it. Can it be done?

Comment: The simple answer is yes. [Ethoslab](http://www.youtube.com/user/ethoslab) has covered this, but I can't remember the exact episode.

Comment: Since you can't get water into the nether I think you have to rig up something with pistons that suffocates them.

Comment: My brother made an elaborate harvester involving using pistons to suffocate them, then throwing a single potion to kill dozens at once.  He gets about 10 levels in experience and a few dozen blaze rods every time he does it.  He spent a long time perfecting it so they have as little HP as possible without killing them *(I think so he still gets the XP?)* - I'll ask him to take a picture of his redstone repeaters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few tutorials for that, and these two designs seemed most notable to me.

First design (by Etho) is complicated, expensive but fully automatic:

And another, simple one (by Generikb) that doesn't require any resources but building blocks:
<sub>You might want to ignore the suggestion to put furnaces there. Smelting doesn't give much experience now.</sub>

If you want to make it even simpler but a bit more efficient, you could just put the spawner in a big solid box, then put one line of fence gates and an empty line below it. That way you'll be able to hit the Blaze and they won't be able to hit you.

Comment: Etho also built one on the Mindcrack server, but if memory serves, that design uses water (melted ice).  Unfortunately, you can't melt ice for water in the nether anymore.